# segregating computers on a network

Tags: vlan

I've currently got 15 computers plugged into a switch along with a cable modem providing internet access.  They all receive their DHCP addresses from the cable modem.  I'd like to segregate the computers so they can't get to each other.  I thought I'd be able to do this with VLANs, but I'm new to managed switches and I'm having trouble figuring out the configuration.  I've currently got a Dell Powerconnect 3524.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called "port isolation". Dell PowerConnect switches do this via *Private VLAN Edge* (PVE). Under the port configuration (near the bottom) is the selector for the "uplink". Unfortunately, it has to be a gig port, but that shouldn't be much of an issue. Attach the cablemodem to "g1" and set all ports to PVE uplink of "g1".

Answer (score 0):

This use case is covered by **Private Vlan**. I only have direct experience with Cisco, however the documentation for your switch, [Dell™ PowerConnect™ 35xx Systems
User’s Guide](http://downloads.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_powerconnect/powerconnect-3524_User%27s%20Guide_en-us.pdf), shows that this feature is available. Page 297 has the port options, the option that should suit your needs is on page 300:

> Private VLAN Edge (PVE)— Indicates the Private VLAN Edge (PVE) group
>   to which the LAG is configured. A port defined as PVE is protected by
>   an uplink, so that it is isolated from other ports within the same
>   VLAN. The uplink must be a GE port.

As I said, I don't have direct experience with Dell, so you should lab this.